# How to make a PDF's hidden signature fields visible?

Tags: itext, hidden, signature, visible

I have a bunch of PDFs with hidden signature fields in them. There is no function to make the actual fields visible; there is only such an option for radio/checkbox/button fields, as far as I have found. Is there any such method or any other way?

I can't add layers to the PDF, as I am trying to turn the fields from hidden to visible, not the other way around.

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
{
    foreach (string key in form.Fields.Keys)
    {
        if (form.GetFieldType(key) == AcroFields.FIELD_TYPE_SIGNATURE)
        {
            al.Add(key);
        }
    }
}

foreach (object x in al)
{
    string s = (string)x;
    AcroFields.Item i = form.GetFieldItem(s);
    stamper.AcroFields.Fields.Remove(s);
    stamper.AcroFields.Fields.Add(s, i);
}
```

This was an attempt of mine to reset the field to make it visible, but it was obvious it wouldn't work since it wouldn't lose all of its properties. So how do I do go about this?

Comment: are you talking about signed PDFs or unsigned PDFs? If signed, forget about it: making signatures visible would break the signature. If not signed, change the rectangle entry in the widget dictionary and create an appearance. Also: what do you mean by "there is only such an option for radio/checkbox/button fields"? That doesn't really make sense. And what do you mean by "I can't add layers to the PDF"? Are you talking about OCG? You need to seriously rephrase your question.

Comment: I just looked for a bunch of anwsers and solution and there was a solution on how to make a field hidden with layers and another one was using BaseField. I just wrote it so people wouldn't give me void anwsers. It aint signed. I just wanted to make the empty field itself invisible. I'll try the widget dictionary thanks.

Comment: Meant visible, not invisible.

Comment: I can't seem to find the exact use of the PDFName(if I am using this correctly) to make a field invisible. Can't find any outside sources for this either

Comment: Now, visible or invisible, what are the fields to begin with and what should they become? If they are invisible and shall become visible, there might be more to do than just manipulate the rectangle.  Invisible fields may not be associated with any page. Thus, making them visible requires you to associate them first. Can you provide a representative sample PDF?

Comment: You're mixing all kinds of things. A PdfName is a structural element that is used in many contexts, but not in the context of making fields visible/invisible. That's done with a flag. As for signatures: they're invisible if the rectangle of their widget annotations has a width and a height equal to 0. You should start by reading the part about appearances in my book about digital signatures: http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures

Comment: I keep mistyping visible. My fields are invisible. I need them to be visible. The fact that they are signatures I think it matters little since its just the box. I think it matter little if i give an example PDF here either cause. I can just make an empty PDF add a hidden signature and upload it here. Whats the point? Anyway flags don't seem to work on making it visible. I tried.......so how do I go around associating a field to a page to make it visible.

Comment: If you think a **representative** example does not help, I think this question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. FYI: Such invisible signature fields may be linked as an annotation from some page (in which case you only need to change the afore mentioned rectangle) or it may not be linked from any page at all (in which case you first have to decide on which page to make the field visible).